# error when making GET request "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, express, xmlhttprequest

Very new to this, but I'm trying to test a small app that performs a GET request to an express end point on localhost server http://localhost:3000/golfpool-standings and uses the returned JSON to display data in html table but when I try using in a script I get 
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
I am testing on live-server http://127.0.0.1:5500/golfApp/index.html
I have hit a wall on this even after looking at similar answers on here. Any help appreciated. My first question so be gentle please.

I can access the end point http://localhost:3000/golfpool-standings from the Chrome browser and JSON returned is displayed on screen, so it seems the backend is working.
https://github.com/paulcullen79/golfApp

```
// index.js
    const data = $.getJSON("http://localhost:3000/golfpool- 
    standings")

// server.js
    const express = require('express')  
    const app = express()

app.get('/golfpool-standings', (req, res) => {
    res.send(data)
})

const port = process.env.port || 3000
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}...`))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line, `$.getJSON("http://localhost:3000/golfpool-standings")` is requesting for a `json` resource but your server is not serving `json`.

From `jQuery` docs:

> As of jQuery 1.4, if the JSON file contains a syntax error, the request will usually fail silently.

Change your server code:

```
app.get('/golfpool-standings', (req, res) => {
  // send data as json
  res.json(data)
})
```

Or change your request to `$.get("http://localhost:3000/golfpool-standings")`

Comment: Thank you very much for the response, I am now getting an object response back, although not sure how to assess the responseJSON of the object, but at least I'm getting a correct response now.

Comment: Got it working when I use the done method with the response. Thanks.